# Docker 1.12 Swarm Service External IP

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Kubernetes allows you to create external IP's for services. In Docker Swarm is it possible to set an endpoint for each service separate from a node IP?

For instance:

```
  node1  192.168.1.22
  node2. 192.168.1.23
```

My service would be:

```
  myweb1  192.168.1.101. 80
```

So I would have tasks running on each node but the service would be accessible at http://192.168.1.101.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. A service in Swarm mode can only be assigned to an Overlay network so the service can't be exposed to the hosts' network without some bridging (ie: using the `--publish` option).

Note that internally (inside the Overlay network), Swarm allocates an ip for each service, irrespective of on which node(s) it runs.

Comment: So can a service on a bridge network be assigned an IP on the "public" network?

Comment: No you can't. You need the service to be sharing the host network to get a separate public IP address and that's not supported although I just see that it's a requested feature https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/989

Why do you want to have an IP for services visible outside the nodes? Typically your have some external load balancer that would send traffic to one of the node, from then on swarm redirects the traffic to the correct traffic. If you export a service at a specific port `--publish 8080:80` then the service will reachable from **any node** at that port.

Comment: @Alkaline, I just saw your comment on your answer.  That --publish <TARGET-PORT>:<SERVICE-PORT> is definitely the ticket and that the service is reachable from any node on the <TARGET-PORT> is awesome.  I've deleted my redundant answer after seeing this.